PHP Script is creating an empty row along with desired row
Currently using React for frontend, php for backend with XAMPP/Apache. When I send a POST using the fetch API, It creates two rows in my table, one empty and one with the correct details. I have verified that the js function only runs once (strict mode not the problem), and verified that the php code runs twice. I am fairly new to php and fetch and am at a loss as to why this is happening.
First row is made incorrectly on first run, not sure how. Second is correct.

register.php:
<?php
require_once('cors.php');
require_once('db_connection.php');

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$username = $data['username'];
$email = $data['email'];
$password = $data['password'];

$street = $data['street'];
$state = $data['state'];
$country = $data['country'];

$fname = $data['fname'];
$lname = $data['lname'];
$phone_number = $data['phone'];

$hashed_password = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

error_log(print_r($country, TRUE)); // prints twice
$sql = "INSERT INTO User (Email, `Password`, Street, `State`, Country, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `Phone Number`, Username)
 VALUES ('$email', '$hashed_password', '$street', '$state', '$country', '$fname', '$lname', '$phone_number', '$username')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result === TRUE) {
    echo json_encode(array("success" => "Account Created Successfully"));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array("error" => "There was an error in your submission"));
}

$conn->close();
?>

register.jsx excerpt
  const onSubmit = e => {

      e.preventDefault() // only prints once
      console.log('hello')
      if (password === rePassword) {

        fetch('http://localhost/teashop/php/register.php', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
          })
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            
            if ('success' in data) {
              setDisplay('login');
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error('Error fetching products:', error);
          }
        );


Warning: You are wide open to SQL Injections and should use parameterized prepared statements instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by PDO or by MySQLi. Never trust any kind of input! Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, you are still in risk of corrupting your data. Escaping is not enough!

It looks like you are using some really bad tutorial. I highly encourage you to find something better. If you are only starting to learn PHP then you should learn PDO instead of mysqli. PDO is much easier and more suitable for beginners. Start here https://phpdelusions.net/pdo & https://websitebeaver.com/php-pdo-prepared-statements-to-prevent-sql-injection. Here are some good video tutorials https://youtu.be/2eebptXfEvw & https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sVbEyFZKgqk&list=PLr3d3QYzkw2xabQRUpcZ_IBk9W50M9pe-

Double-check your browser's Network tool to see if something is triggering this script twice

To address some comments: I have to use this configuration as its for a school project with predefined technologies. Additionally I am at no risk of SQL Injections as this will never go to production and is just for a demo.

you call e.preventDefault() but I think your form is submitted anyway. So the php file is called two times: one from register.jsx and another from browser. You can try to write inside form tag onsubmit="return false"

Whether you're likely to be at risk of SQL injection in a practical sense is somewhat beside the point - as a learner you should get into good habits early on. In fact that's exactly when you should learn to do it properly, rather than having to change your approach later on if you continue to write computer programs. No competent educator should ever show you that structure for building a query in the first place. While you may be required to use mysqli rather than PDO for your project, that doesn't prevent you from parameterising your query properly.

And it's not just about security either, it's also a reliability issue - right now anyone with a name like O'Reilly or that sort of thing would crash your query because the ' in the name would be taken literally by SQL and it would terminate the string it's within, causing a SQL syntax error (because Reilly isn't a SQL command, but it would be, from the database's point of view, outside the name string, which is terminated by the ' after the O. With a parameterised query there is no possiblity for a mistake like that to occur.

I have solved my issue thanks to some comments. My php scripts were not handling preflights.
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'OPTIONS') {
    require_once('cors.php');
    exit;
}


Exiting as above with Cors preflight prevents the empty table from being created. I will also work on properly sanitizing user input.
